# Referencing a form assigned to a variable in jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with id='form1' as well as another one with 'form2'. On submit, i want to pass both forms as objects to a single validate function which can validate them. I am confused on how to do this.
If i do something like

```
var form = $('#form1');
Validate(form);
```

how do i access the text-fields of the variable form?
i don't want to write duplicate validate functions as both forms are ALMOSt similar.

Comment: you need to provide more information like what are the validations and what are the fields etc

Comment: You could pass the form ID to the function instead of the whole form.

Comment: @Arun: Well consider a form with 2 inputs both numbers and the validate checks if indeed user inputs numbers. i don't think solution depends on what the validation and form content is.

Comment: @Sergio: Good idea. Would do it but would wait for an answer on passing forms too, to see if it is possible or not to pass forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following also...

[A Complete example is here...](http://jsfiddle.net/v5spB/2/)

```
function validate(formid){
    var form = $("#"+formid);
    var name = form.find("#name");
    var number = form.find("#number");
    alert(name.val());
    alert(number.val());
}

    validate("form1");
    validate("form2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/). Your form will serve as the context and you could reuse it for different forms.

See below:

```
var form = $('#form1');
function Validate(form){
    var field1 = form.find(".field1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the name of the fields, you can do this:

```
function Validate(form) {
  form = form[0]; // raw element
  if (check_syntax(form.name.value)) { doSomething(); }
  if (check_syntax(form.email.value)) { doSomething(); }
  if (check_syntax(form.anotherfield.value)) { doSomething(); }
}
```

If every field in the form has a name, you can access it via form.fieldName or form['fieldName'].

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both forms are similar:

```
ValidateForm($("#form1, #form2"));

function ValidateForm(forms){

   forms.each(function(){

      $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function(){

        //Do something to validate text field


      })

      $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){

        //Do something to validate checkbox


      })

    })

 }
```

Comment: Thanks. But both forms are not validated at same times. Validation is event based.